# weird behaviour when calling external script

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, bash, console

My C++ program is just a very simple while loop in which I grab user command from the console (standard input, stdin) using the getline() blocking function. Every now and then I must call an external bash script for other purposes. The script is not directly related to what the user do, it just do some stuff on the filesystem but it has to print text lines in the console standard output (stdout) to inform the user about the outcome of its computations.

What I get is that as soon as the script starts and prints stuff to stdout, the getline() function behave has it were non-blocking (it is supposed to block until the user inputs some text). As a consequence, the while(1) starts spinning at full speed and the CPU usage skyrockets to a near 100%.

I narrowed down the problem to a single C++ source file which reproduces the problem in the same exact way, here it is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int pid = fork(); // spawn

    if(pid > 0)
    {   
        // child thread
        system("sleep 5; echo \"you're screwed up!!!\"");
    }
    else
    {       
        // main thread
        std::string input;
        while(1)
        {
            std::cout << std::endl << "command:";
            getline(std::cin, input);
        }
    }
}
```

In this particular case after 5 seconds the program starts spamming "\ncommand:" on stdout and the only way to stop it is sending a SIGKILL signal. Sometimes you have to press some keys on the keyboard before the program starts spamming text lines.

Let run this code for 10 seconds then press any key on the keyboard. Be sure to be ready to fire the SIGKILL signal to the process from another console. You can use the command `killall -9 progname`

Comment: In which environment you tried? I tried running your program and i got `command:you're screwed up!!!` and program exited.

Comment: Linux CentOS6. However it doesn't exit, actually. Try to press some keys on that console and it should start spamming text lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if failbit or eof is set?

Comment: nice catch! std::cin.good() returns false so either eof, fail or bad bit is set.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following line of your code

```
if (pid > 0)
```

to

```
if (pid == 0)
```

`fork()` returns 0 to child and pid of child to parent. In your example, you are running `system()` in parent and exiting the parent. The child then becomes orphan process running in a `while(1)` loop which i guess is messing up with the stdin, stdout.

I have modified your program to run `system()` in child process.

Comment: mm that's ok. It solves the problem on the proof of concept program but not on the original one. In the original I use boost::thread and there's no such pid to examine

Comment: Just try to make sure you run the `system()` in the child thread and `getline()` in the parent thread.

Comment: so the main problem is that the child become orphan and starts messing with the stdout? Please, can you explain more in depth what's going on? Why the getline() starts to behave has a non blocking function?

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem:

```
if(pid > 0)
    {   
        // child thread
        system("sleep 5; echo \"you're screwed up!!!\"");
    }
```

this is the PARENT. ;) The child gets `pid` : `0`.

Comment: see my comment on the answer above

Comment: @G_G we answered the question. You got answer to what you asked. So, it this answers are correct, accept them - and ask another question - with the real code on which you need help..